# Difference between Thesis and Research paper?

Tags: publications, research-process, thesis, research-undergraduate

My query is about whats the main difference between thesis and research paper, and as i am undergrad, which is more easy for an undergrad to do!!

Comment: "which is more easy for an undergrad to do"?? It is not clear what this means... You might want to add more details of what you already know...

Comment: I think this could be a good question if you add a small additional amount of context.

Answer (score 2):

An undergraduate thesis (or dissertation) [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis): a document submitted in support of candidature for an academic degree, which presents the author's findings.

By comparison, a research paper (when differentiated from undergraduate life) [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_publishing#Scholarly_paper): an academic work containing original research results or a review of existing results, which are typically published after a peer-review process successfully checks suitability.

For an undergraduate, I suspect an undergraduate thesis is easier, since I believe the bar for acceptance is generally lower than the bar for acceptance of peer-review.

Comment: The ordinary meaning of a research paper is an undergraduate or secondary school assignment.  Surely this is what the asker means.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist According to Wikipedia, there are [four types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_paper) of _research paper_, which includes an academic work and a thesis. We can discount thesis here, and I assume an academic work is most likely, since the alternatives - a position paper and a term paper - don't seem like substitutes for a thesis. Of course, I may have assumed incorrectly and will refine my answer if the OP clarifies.

Comment: @user2768 What i meant by research paper is that, I want to publish a paper on my own with some external help and this paper is not to get a degree or to get credits for my college work.

Comment: @yashkarbhari That sounds like an academic paper. Since _this paper is not to get a degree or to get credits for my college work_, I presume you are wondering how hard it is relative to a thesis, in order to decide whether you should pursue it? Perhaps you can edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score -3):

A thesis might be longer and might be written over a longer period of time.  There is not guaranteed to be any difference.

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/academia-varies-more-than-you-think-it-does-the-movie#4478

Comment: I am not sure if this suits as an answer...